# What could be causing this error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null

I am currently learning js through udemy and video tutorials, and been having many successes and many struggles. On thing I am working on is using a button to play an mp3 audio file. Right now, it works and it plays, but I would like to put it in a variable / object of some sort so I can add a pause method. However, whenever I try to store it, I get this error not at build but when I click on the button:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play')

This is my code that works:

import sound from './Pics/Senorita.mp3'

```
function main({  }) {
  const AudioClick = () => {  
    new Audio(sound).play();
   };
    return (
       <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", 'fontSize': '40px'}}>
          <BsFillPlayCircleFill onClick={AudioClick}></BsFillPlayCircleFill>
       </div>
   );
}

export default main;
```

As you can see here, although this works it simply starts a new audio file, so I am unable to access it again. If I press the button multiple times, it will just overlap.

This is one of many solutions I have attempted:
let x = document.getElementById(sound);
x.play();

but most things I try give the same error. This makes me think it is an issue with the sorce, but I am not sure because it works well in the first method as shown. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am new to posting on stack overflow, so I hope this question is appropriately written, feel free to leave constructive feedback.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: what does `sound` reference to in your main function? I dont see it declared anywhere or as prop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is imported, it is shown above the code what I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign your **audio element** to a variable in **React**, you probably need to add **hooks** to your application: in this case the `useState` and the `useEffect` hooks.
You can find a lot of information about hooks on the web, so I'll just focus on solving your problem. (Anyway, if you want to read something more about **hooks**, start here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Let's start by declaring a `setState` **hook** that we'll use to set your variable

```js
const [audioElement, setAudioElement] = useState();
```

To make sure this code only runs once, so you only have one instance of your audio element, we set its value inside a `useEffect` hook, with an empty array as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setAudioElement(new Audio('https://file-examples.com/storage/fe91f66a2a65f065f9ba741/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'));
}, []);
```

(I've found the audio source on this website, just to make sure we have a file that works https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-mp3-download/).

At this point we can add the two methods that will start and stop the sound.

```js
// start
const AudioStartClick = () => {  
  audioElement.play();
};
// stop
const AudioStopClick = () => {  
  audioElement.pause();
};
```

##### Bonus

As explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio, we are **not 100% sure** that an **audio element** is able to **play** right away, so we might add an **event listener** to make sure we can use that element.

In order to accomplish this, we need to add a new `useState` hook to manage a **Boolean**, and a new `useEffect` hook to **listen** to the event.

```js
const [canPlay, setCanPlay] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  audioElement?.addEventListener("canplaythrough", (event) => {
    setCanPlay(true);
  });
}, [audioElement]);
```

Now that we have this information, we just need to add a couple of lines to make sure that we don't call play or stop on an element that is not capable of playing.

```js
// start
const AudioStartClick = () => {
  if (!canPlay) return;
  audioElement.play();
};
// stop
const AudioStopClick = () => {
  if (!canPlay) return;
  audioElement.pause();
};
```

Finally, here is the complete code example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App(props) {

  const [audioElement, setAudioElement] = useState();
  const [canPlay, setCanPlay] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAudioElement(new Audio('https://file-examples.com/storage/fe91f66a2a65f065f9ba741/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'));
  }, []);

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio
  useEffect(() => {
    audioElement?.addEventListener("canplaythrough", (event) => {
      setCanPlay(true);
    });
  }, [audioElement]);


  const AudioStartClick = () => {  
    if (!canPlay) return;
    audioElement.play();
   };

   const AudioStopClick = () => {  
    if (!canPlay) return;
    audioElement.pause();
   };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={AudioStartClick}> Start </button>
      <button onClick={AudioStopClick}> Stop </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful, and exactly what I've been looking for. I really appreciate it

Comment: @MayaTomarchio Glad it helped, please accept the answer and upvote if you can.

Comment: sadly I am too new to vote but accepted!